# Recording data on DB table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is it possible to have a table and insert data n a single row on two different occasion? I mean, I have a table with five column and on first data submission, i want to record data on only just two field on that table, and in different data submission on that same row, I would want to record data on those 3 remaining column that haven't been recorded with any data. What method should i use? INSERT or UPDATE? Or neither?

Sorry for my bad english and confusing way of asking question.

Code:

```
  $query = ("SELECT q1 FROM grades where studentnumber = '$_POST[studentnumber]' && subjectcode = '$_POST[subjectcode]' ");
 $result=mysql_query($query);
 if($result)
  {

if(mysql_num_rows($result) ==1)
    {

      $sql=mysql_query("UPDATE grades SET q1 = '$_POST[q1]' where studentnumber = '$_POST[studentnumber]' AND subjectcode = '$_POST[subjectcode]'"); 

        if($sql) 
          { 
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Password successfully changed'); location.href = 'cvsu-sis_grades.php';</script>";
          }
    }
    }
    else
  { 
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Record Does not Exist'); location.href = 'cvsu-sis_grades.php';</script>";
  }
```

i omitted some columns just to make the coed shorter but most likely it is the same. just a series of q1,  q2, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INSERT for first two columns, and get your inserted id using mysql_insert_id() (only if your primary key column name is "id") and using this you can update your remaining three columns using UPDATE

Answer (score 2):

The first query should be an `INSERT`, then you can get the last inserted id and do an `UPDATE` query

Comment: i've tried it but nothing is recorded. does it have something to do swith null or not null values?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to make sure, that when you insert the 2 fields on your first `INSERT`, the fields you leave empty are allowed to be `NULL`!

You have to `INSERT`the first data into the table and later on, when you want to add the remaining fields, you have to `UPDATE` that row. Make sure that, when you `UPDATE`, you are using a `WHERE`-constraint (e.g. with the 2 fields already entered), otherwise all rows will be updated!